# Android. SetCompoundDrawables is not working

Tags: android

I'm try to set right-drawable to a TextView (in header of list view). I'm setting up the bounds but it's not helping. setDrawablesWithInstrinctBounds() works fine.

Here is code:

```
private View getHeaderView() {
    final LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.legislation_article_list_header, null, false);
    final TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.sEdition);
    headerSpinner = textView;

    final Drawable d = getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.spinner_arrow_down);
    d.setBounds(new Rect(0, 0, headerSpinner.getHeight(), headerSpinner.getHeight()));
    headerSpinner.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, d, null);

    textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

       .............

        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Use `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, d, null);`

Comment: To add padding, you might use `android:drawablePadding="8dp"` in xml or `setCompoundDrawablePadding(12)` in Java.

Answer (score 12):

Try this:

```
Drawable d = getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.spinner_arrow_down);
d.setBounds(new Rect(0, 0, headerSpinner.getHeight(), headerSpinner.getHeight()));
textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( d , null, null, null);
```

or

```
textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( R.drawable.smiley, 0, 0, 0);
```